# How to take the backup of live sql server 2005 express DB

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

How to take the backup of live sql server 2005 express DB ? At any given time some transaction are in progress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [How to: Create a Full Database Backup (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191304.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

[BACKUP DATABASE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186865.aspx) does this:

> SQL Server uses an online backup process to allow a database backup while the database is still in use. During a backup, most operations are possible; for example, `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, or `DELETE` statements are allowed during a backup operation.
>
> Operations that cannot run during a database or transaction log backup include:
>
> - File management operations such as the `ALTER DATABASE` statement with either the `ADD FILE` or `REMOVE FILE` options.
> - Shrink database or shrink file operations. This includes auto-shrink operations.

Answer (score 1):

Refer this [msdn link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqldisasterrecovery/thread/3d3f91a7-50c6-41bc-9e5d-1526d574bc3d)